# Azure data factory concurrency and dependencies

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am building a pipeline in ADF where I want to replicate what I have in a databricks job. [image: databricks job] Is has some dependencies and I was wondering how can I do the same in ADF in order to maximize the parallel runs.

Right now I just divided the notebooks in 5 stages [image: ADF] (right now I have only created 3 stages) and was going to run the notebooks on stage 2 only after stage 1 finishes, etc., but I was wondering if I can do something similar to what I have in databricks so I can run notebooks from different stages in parallel and have the same dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can run activities in parallel in ADF too. Just connect them to all the activities they are dependent on.
[image: activity dependencies]